# Reading strings from file and copying them in an Array - C

Tags: c, arrays, file

I'm trying to read some strings from a file, and copy them into a string array.
I can't understand why I manage to read properly just the first of the strings in the file, before getting a segmentation fault. I know that each string in the file has up to 50 characters.

```
...

int i = 0;
char s[50]; 
int N=0;
FILE *fp;

//Figures out how many strings are stored in the file
while(fgets(s, 50, fp)!=NULL){N++}  

rewind(fp);

char *strings[N];  //This is the array where I want to store strings

for(i=0;i<N;i++){

    fgets(s, 50, fp);
    strcpy(strings[i], s);
    printf("%s", s );
}
```

Why I can't store succesfully strings into the array ?

Comment: You can not use `strcpy` with an uninitialized pointer, use `strdup`: `strings[i] = strdup(s);`

Comment: Hint: `char *strings[N]` is an array of N pointers, but none of them has been initialized. Each of the pointers points to some undeterminate memory location.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Thanks a lot! So i can use strcpy, but I need to initialize each  `strings[i]` pointer. Do you think that after the fgets() I should use something like : `strings[i] = (char*)malloc(50*sizeof(char));` ?

Comment: change `char *strings[N]` to `char strings[N][50]`. And BTW, you can `fgets` the data directly into `strings[i]` (no need to retrieve the data into a temporary buffer and then `strcpy` it into the permanent buffer). And BTW, you probably want to use a little more than 50, in order to account for the null character required at the end of each string, and to the new-line character that `fgets` appends to each string (if my memory serves me correctly).

Comment: `malloc(50*sizeof(char))` : yes this would be possible, but you can allocate less memory if your string is shorter that 49 characters.

Comment: Yes, you can use `malloc` and then copy (don't use `strcpy`),  I will use `size_t len = strlen(s) + 1; strings[i] = malloc(len); snprintf(strings[i], len, "%s", s);`

Comment: @KeineLust why not `strcpy` ? `snprintf` is overkill here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz `strcpy` [is not safe](https://blog.liw.fi/posts/strncpy/)

Comment: That's a nice use case for `strdup` which is more or less the combination of `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: @KeineLust: `strcpy` is not unsafe if you can know that the allocated array can receive the copy. As you have just allocated the correct size, it is perfectly safe to use `strcpy`. You are free to avoid it, but you should not advise not to use it when it can be safely...

Comment: @SergeBallesta, you are right, maybe my claim is a little radical, I rephrase: `snprintf` is used as defensive coding against buffer overflows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two mistakes:

1- when copying strings, you have to allocate memory for the destination, inyour case the destination is strings[i] for which you haven't allocated any memory

2-your strings must be null terminated

This code should work:

```
   #define MAX_STRINGS 100
   int i = 0;
   char s[50]; 
   int N=0;
   while(fgets(s, 50, fp)!=NULL){N++;}
   char strings[MAX_STRINGS][50];

   rewind(fp);
    for(i=0;i<N && i<MAX_STRINGS;i++){

        fgets(s, 50, fp);
        strcpy(strings[i], s);
        printf("%s", s );
    }
```

Note that if you are not using vectors, you have to pre-define the size of your array, basically the size of the array must be a constant

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using vectors, but also without cursor-ing(?) through the file more than once?